# div background resize for contain

Tags: css, sass, bootstrap-5

I'm using Bootstrap 5.3 to build a mobile-first layout. I have a div that has a background image, and that will have images overlaid over it:

```
<div className="d-flex flex-column">
  <div className={styles["city-container"]}>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
.city-container {
  background-color: #839E43;
  background-image: url("/images/city/city-bg.png");
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  position: relative;
}
```

The problem is that the `100vh` causes the div to stretch the full height of the page (obviously). How can I limit the height of the div to the height of the scaled (`background-size: contain`) background image?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Div with background-image and height auto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54673645/div-with-background-image-and-height-auto) - TLDR: Use an `img`-element and not a `background` as the `background-image` doesn't have any dimensions in the DOM

Comment: If it is a background image, a `background-image` should be used. Only use `<img>` for "real" images.

Comment: @cloned If so - Then how would OP solve this issue?

Comment: You know the aspect ratio of your image, so make the div use the same aspect ratio - either via the `aspect-ratio` property, or the "padding-bottom hack".

Comment: @DarkBee I would argue that the image is not necessarily content, but decoration. I suppose it would be possible to just use the img tag, but I also need to position other images over this.

Comment: The `aspect-ratio` @CBroe mentioned should work tho

Comment: If you're worried about the semantics / accessibility, when using an `img` for what is essentially a background image, you can indicate that it has "presentational" purposes only, https://kb.daisy.org/publishing/docs/html/images-deco.html

Comment: _"I suppose it would be possible to just use the img tag, but I also need to position other images over this."_ - you can still do that, when using an `img` element. Your "background" image is kept in normal flow, so that it will "span up" a div container you put around it, to the necessary height. And then you simply position the other images in that container absolute, using the container as reference point (by giving it `position: relative`)